# -webkit-appearance: none Dropdown icon issue

Tags: html, css

To fix safari dropdown styling issue added -webkit-appearance: none. This removed dropdown icon(small down arrow) in chrome and other browsers.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Example for your:

1) Styled dropdown in select box

```
<div class="myBox">
  <select class="mySelect" name="currency">
     <option value="Please_select" selected> Please select</option>
     <option value="aud">AUD</option>
     <option value="usd">USD</option>
     <option value="eur">EUR</option>
     <option value="gbp">GBP</option>
     <option value="jpy">JPY</option>
     <option value="nzd">NZD</option>
  </select>
</div>

.myBox{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
.myBox:after {
    content: "▼";
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    background:#fff;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    color:#999;
    font-size:14px;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.mySelect{
    border: 0;
    background: #fff;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 410px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

2) Set none dropdown

```
.myBox:after {
        content: "";
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        background:#fff;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        text-align:center;
        color:#999;
        font-size:14px;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f9ju0gdk/

Comment: I tried this but the issue is when you click on that dropdown icon it doesn't work. So I used -webkit-appearance: menulist.

Comment: add more css code

.myBox:hover:after {
    content: "▲";
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    background:#fff;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    color:#999;
    font-size:14px;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}